# Microstrategy triggering batch process

Tags: linux, database, shell, microstrategy

I am new to Microstrategy. I was wondering if it is possible to pass a few parameters to a program (for example a python script), run it at back end and display rows from a table once that program updates the table. I have had discussions about how Microstrategy could be used to insert into a table and a trigger could pick parameters from the table. But I am not exactly sure as to how this can be done. If anyone could tell me 
1. is it even possible to do what I have outlined?
2. If yes, please detail the steps.

Comment: I think you can get more answers if you provides more details about your problem. Do you want to report on the same table where you are inserting the data? Which database are you using? In theory you can use a freeform sql report to call a db function (passing some prompted values) and get a table in return, but not all db have this kind of functionality

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the documentation on Microstrategy's web services ?
https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/_CurrentGARelease/docs/projects/WebSDK/default.htm#topics/webservices/What_is_Web_Services_.htm
What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Microstrategy can update table through some post-sql.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing Transaction Services, a user can pass parameters to a stored procedure

The procedure, in turn, can use a SYSTEM Curl to interact with an API set up to trigger python code, providing the intended variables with it.

The procedure can be set up to wait for a response from the Curl, in turn resulting in MicroStrategy waiting for the result of the run to be complete.

If the python script stores results in a table, MicroStrategy reporting can be built from to read from this table, thus returning results of the python script after having passed parameters into it.